# sbcl end of file: dose not get data from input stream

Tags: sbcl, quicklisp

Hi friends I am following this method to get data from another server.This fails at (`rdbms-update-database-from-rpc`). Giving an error:

> Run sbcl : $ sbcl
>      Install the dependencies once :
>      * (ql:quickload '("cl-json" "cl-dbi" "drakma" "flexi-streams" "ironclad" "local-time"))
>      * (push "/absolute path to parser code/" asdf:*central-registry*)
>      * (require 'peercoin-blockchain-parser)
>      * (in-package peercoin-blockchain-parser)
>   To create and update a database from scratch using a running db  daemon :
>      * (rdbms-initialize-database)
>      * (rdbms-update-database-from-rpc)
>   To get the list of the 20 richest addresses :
>      * (rdbms-get-rich-addresses 20)
>
> ERROR:
>   sbcl: debugger invoked on a END-OF-FILE in thread #:   end of file on #